# How to merge borders of multiple img and fulfill imgs completely to div

Tags: html, css

I have two questions:

1. How can I merge the borders of multiple images? I have 4 images in a row and there's space between each so the borders are separated.
2. I want each of the four images of each div to fully fill the div to both right and left.

```css
img {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.works {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="works" id="works">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is coming because `<img>` are `inline-block` elements by default and `inline-block` elements take space to align itself.

You can use **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)** to remove the spaces...

...and to merge the borders you can use `margin` negative values.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.works {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="works" id="works">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
    <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding `float:left;` to your images, you can remove the gap.

Then, by only adding a left border to the first image per row, and only adding a top border to the first row of images, you can make the borders more even.

```css
img {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  float: left;
}
#works .img:first-child img {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.img img:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <div class="works" id="works">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
        <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
        <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
        <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
        <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
        <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
        <img src="http://up.pestools.ir/151810863547341_works1.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
```